# JPA one-to-one mapping creates an extra column. How to remove it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have one-to-one mapping JPA table in my springboot application which works fine.
The `Users` is the parent table and in the `account_no` column, it stores the foreign key. Which is, child's primary key. The child is `Account` table.

However, when the application is started, I can see that there is one additional column (`user_id`) that has been created in H2 DB. I think it is something wrong with my JPA mapping. Pls help to figure it out. Below are the two classes.

```
@Entity
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    // Other fields related to user entity go here ..

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_no", referencedColumnName = "account_num")
    private Account account;
}

@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractEntity{

    // fields like account#, balance etc goes here..

    @Column(name="account_num", unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private long accountNo;

    @OneToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private User user;
}
```

---

Startup log.

```
 create table account (id bigint not null,  account_num bigint not null, bal float not null, user_id bigint, primary key (id))
2021-12-22 00:09:28.765 DEBUG 25380 --- [           main] org.hibernate.SQL                        :
```

Answer (score 3):

Decide which side should contain the extra column and use the `mappedBy` attribute. Then JPA will do what's needed

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, mappedBy = "user")
private Account account;
```

Considering that you have bidirectional mapping you don't need the `@JoinColumn` that  you have used.

Just both `@OneToOne` annotations and the decision which would be owner entity of the relation by using the mappedBy attribute on one of those annotations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but few questions, 1. Mapped by must be added into the non-owning side right? who is not holding the relationship? In this case it is `Account` entity. Here the parent is `User` entity, who is holding the account no as the foreign key. (https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-one-to-one)
2. Letting JPA decide means, JPA will create a column in DB at runtime? 
3. If I want to control what is the column name rather than JPA to decide, how to handle it, what are changes should be done to my code?

Comment: The missing thing that I haven't understood is, in a bi-directional relationship, I cannot avoid having foreign key columns on both tables. Is it?

Answer (score 0):

> It depends on you in which side you store the extra column which was a
> foreign  key.Because When You started to established oneToOne
> relationship between two table it is mandatory to store  user's
> primary key in account table as a foreign key, or  account table
> primary key in user table as foreign key.You should be need to declare
> mappedBy and your tables reference name.for example if you declare
> mappedBy="user" in account table it create an extra account_id column
> in user table as a foreign key, Same as for account

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "user")
private Account account;
```

> Don't need to declare these things in side OneToOne annotation cascade
> = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, By default it always support lazy fetch

.

Comment: I'd recommend being explicit even when there is default behavior. For one, it reduces accidental bugs, and secondly, it is easier for people to work on the codebase as they don't need complete knowledge about everything being used to understand it.

Comment: @Jumboturn  If I add ` mappedBy = "user"` in User entity, then the account number is not saved in the user table. which is not my expectation. On the other way, if I add ` mappedBy = "account" in Account entity, then I cannot retrieve the user details, and it's giving a JPA error.